# Encrypting Data using RSA Public and Private Key in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am trying to encrypt a message using RSA public key and decrypt it using my private key. It encrypted the message, but I was not able to decrypt it.  The message was still encrypt after the final process.  When I exported the private key, it also included the public keys. I tried to remove the public key leaving, but it would not work.
Here are the private and public keys

```
//This is the public key
private const string public_key =  "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>uznzVPilsR1rWPkpq6m6IALaafDnVZTDDcnEyBD3A/PBx2JZTKM0DTgiTDDwCEmQBNBpPILcIBdtg3aSUgicair+2ksYrVFT+uiy0Zy1nU6qoJ+SsapLKrpCa1zHpV4LMO/pFo4Foqzw0C1FNe56FXo1xj77GPgeYl0MHUVtAUc=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";

//This is the private and public key.
private const String private_key = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>uznzVPilsR1rWPkpq6m6IALaafDnVZTDDcnEyBD3A/PBx2JZTKM0DTgiTDDwCEmQBNBpPILcIBdtg3aSUgicair+2ksYrVFT+uiy0Zy1nU6qoJ+SsapLKrpCa1zHpV4LMO/pFo4Foqzw0C1FNe56FXo1xj77GPgeYl0MHUVtAUc=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>+jPKs9JxpCSzNY+YNanz49Eo/A6RaU1DZWoFm/bawffZOompeL1jzpUlJUIrKVZJkNFvlxE90uXVwjxWBLv9BD==</P><Q>v5CVWKZ5Wo7W0QyoEOQS/OD8tkKS9DjzZnbnuo6lhcMaxsBrCWLstac1Xm2oFNtZgLtrPGbPfCNC5Su4Rz/P5w==</Q><DP>ZnyikmgobqEt20m3gnvcUDxT+nOJMsYYTklQhONoFj4M+EJ9bdy+Lle/gHSLM4KJ3c08VXgVh/bnSYnnfkb20Q==</DP><DQ>sSYGRfWk0W64Dpfyr7QKLxnr+Kv186zawU2CG44gWWNEVrnIAeUeWxnmi41CWw9BZH9sum2kv/pnuT/F6PWEzw==</DQ><InverseQ>XpWZQKXa1IXhF4FX3XRXVZGnIQP8YJFJlSiYx6YcdZF24Hg3+Et6CZ2/rowMFYVy+o999Y5HDC+4Qa1yWvW1vA==</InverseQ><D>Kkfb+8RrJqROKbma/3lE3xXNNQ7CL0F5CxQVrGcN8DxL9orvVdyjlJiopiwnCLgUHgIywceLjnO854Q/Zucq6ysm2ZRq36dpGLOao9eg+Qe8pYYO70oOkEe1HJCtP1Laq+f3YK7vCq7GkgvKAI9uzOd1vjQv7tIwTIADK19ObgE=</D></RSAKeyValue>";

//Encrypting the text using the public key
private RSACryptoServiceProvider cipher = null;
cipher = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            cipher.FromXmlString(public_key);
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtUnencrypt.Text);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.Encrypt(data, false);
            lblUnencryptMessage.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);

        //    decryptText();

//Trying to decrypt the text using the private key

cipher = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            cipher.FromXmlString(private_key);

            byte[] ciphterText = Convert.FromBase64String(lblUnencryptMessage.Text);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.Decrypt(ciphterText, false);
            lblDecript.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(plainText);
```

For example, I encrypted the word "Testing", the encrypted text was

```
kkqs+UGHNI7/3cKhQvSnJrKzNeCBQX9xHX2VrlyMvnwtszJAoFuViBZlfwmpVhqddnVUrlaqqkD7971E8L3wWltfGetK9nIljeo0GeietLYljoY0Gy3gatU++JPrqajAKxpIB75tvVlKXuYIs0qE3XWZu9bj0zAa4BVT2MhVNQM="
```

The decrypted text was

```
dGVzdGluZw==
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: When I try to run your code it throws an exception. What happens when you run it?

Comment: @GregS, It did not give me an exception, it simply did not decrypt the text. I updated the original text to include an example.

Comment: How did you generate the key ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There appears to be nothing wrong with the encryption/decryption code, just how you're handling the decrypted data. Specifically this line:

```
lblDecript.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(plainText);
```

You are taking the decrypted data and Base64 encoding it, which is why you get: dGVzdGluZw== (since this is the Base64 encoded version of the string "testing").

You need to use the following instead:

```
lblDecript.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
```

This should correctly convert the decrypted byte array to a the original string.